# Seek for all paths between two nodes except one type of node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to draw graph with all connections (paths) between two nodes except paths with specific type of node.

For example I'm looking paths between A and B except connection via node of type X.

So as result I want to get all paths from A to B except this one via node of type X, for example A -> C (type different than X) -> B  - ok, A -> D (type X) -> B not ok.

Of course number of nodes on paths could be > 2.

I wrote something like this but I don't know how to achieve this

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:'Brad Pitt'}), (p2:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'}), 
paths=allShortestPaths((p1)-[*]-(p2))
UNWIND nodes(paths) as rel
RETURN paths, collect(distinct labels(rel)) as types
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this one, you'll want a path variable, and you'll use a `none()` predicate to ensure no nodes in the path have the type you want to exclude.

To use your example, if we had :Director nodes and you wanted to exclude paths with these nodes, you might do so like this:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:'Brad Pitt'}), (p2:Person {name:'Tom Hanks'}), 
path=allShortestPaths((p1)-[*]-(p2))
WHERE none(node in nodes(path) WHERE node:Director)
RETURN path
```